# Entity Framework is failing to delete a record from an associated table throwing an error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a simple association table whose PK isn't referenced anywhere but when I am trying to delete a record from it in the following way, I get an error. I am using EF code-first. Any help would be very very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
List<ViolationTypeNOV> novRels = UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).Include("ViolationType").Include("NOV").ToList();

foreach (ViolationTypeNOV o in novRels)
{
     UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.Remove(o);
}                
UnitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the error message I am getting. If the table's PK isn't referenced in any way, why is it failing with this error? Just not able to understand:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

The same thing if I am running through SSMS same thing is working though:

```
DELETE ViolationTypeNOVs 
WHERE ViolationTypeNOVId = 2
```

Why?

But again if I am running the same query through context as below, I get the same error at the calling `SaveChanges`:

```
foreach (ViolationTypeNOV o in novRels)
{
    string str = string.Format("Delete ViolationTypeNOVs where ViolationTypeNOVId = {0}", new object[] { o.ViolationTypeNOVId });
    UnitOfWork.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(str);
}

UnitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges();
```

It seems like some of the objects within the context aren't nulling or getting deleted, is there anyway to clear them all in one go? Because these ids/objects are used in multiple places in the code - please let me know how to clear them all - thanks a lot.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - the problem is we need to clear up all the objects and its links that the parent object is using then only we can save the changes thanks here is my solution

```
    public bool Delete(NOV nov, bool performCommit = true)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction dbOperation = null;
        if (performCommit)
            dbOperation = UnitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            //-- Remove the Items - "foreach" approach was a problem
            // http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-pitfalls-deleting-orphans

            //------------------------------------------------------
            // Remove the Violations that are in this NOV
            //------------------------------------------------------
            List<Violation> violationIdlist = new List<Violation>();

            foreach (var v in nov.ViolationNOVs)
            {
                var a = UnitOfWork.ViolationRepository.GetAll().Where(z => z.ViolationId == v.ViolationId).FirstOrDefault();
                violationIdlist.Add(a);                    
            }

            foreach (var v in violationIdlist)
            {
                var a = nov.ViolationNOVs.Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId && x.ViolationId == v.ViolationId)?.FirstOrDefault();
                nov.ViolationNOVs.Remove(a);
            }

            nov.IssuedBy.Clear();

            //deleting all OneToMany references to NOV                
            List<ViolationTypeNOV> novRels = UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).Include("ViolationType").Include("NOV").ToList();                
            nov?.ViolationTypeNOVs?.Clear();                
            //foreach (ViolationTypeNOV o in novRels)
            //{
            //    UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.Remove(o);
            //    o?.ViolationType?.ViolationTypeNOVs?.Remove(o);                   
            //    nov?.ViolationTypeNOVs?.Remove(o);
            //}
            UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.RemoveRange(novRels);             

            List<ViolationNOV> violationNOVs = UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationNOVs.Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).Include("Violation").Include("NOV").ToList();
            nov?.ViolationNOVs?.Clear();
            UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationNOVs.RemoveRange(violationNOVs);            

            List<CaseNOV> caseNOVs = UnitOfWork.Context.CaseNOVs.Where(x => x.NOVId == nov.NOVId).Include("Case").Include("NOV").ToList();
            nov?.CaseNOVs?.Clear();
            UnitOfWork.Context.CaseNOVs.RemoveRange(caseNOVs);

            UnitOfWork.Context.SaveChanges();
            if (dbOperation != null)
                dbOperation.Commit();

            LogHandler.LogInfo(2521, "Deleted NOV " + nov.NOVNumber);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHandler.LogError(2523, "Commit Fail in NOV Delete", ex);
            if (dbOperation != null)
                dbOperation.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This statement has fixed the problem: UnitOfWork.Context.ViolationTypeNOVs.RemoveRange(novRels); thanks a lot for everybody who tried to help me